# ANTLR4 c++ Target - UTF8 conversion error in http parser

Tags: antlr4

i'm trying to use antlr4 to build http parser according to grammar in [RFC 7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230). I generated parser by antlr tool, and put it into my code. But when I'm trying to put data from browser (via tcp server) I got exception: `UTF-8 string contains an illegal byte sequence`.

If I understood correctly the RFC, I don't need any conversion to UTF-8, because data in header are in US ASCII, and body is simply set of bytes.

Can I disable conversion data to UTF-8 in antlr?

Thanks for advice

Comment: Instead of switching off something that is well tested (and actually necessary), you should rather check your input to see why it is not UTF-8.

Comment: @MikeLischke Because it is not necessary to have input in UTF-8 in HTTP protocol. Message body is defined in RFC as: `message_body : OCTET*;` and OCTET is defined as: `'OCTET: \u0000'..'\u00FF';`

The reason is the body can have data in any other encoding then UTF-8

Comment: OK, then it's pretty clear what to do: convert the message to UTF-8. You have to handle all the possible encodings anyway, but this is not the task of a parser.

Comment: But... Handling all possible encodings without know, what is the encoding of source is impossible? Information about encoding is in header... which I have to parse to get information.

I think, the better way will be to write own parser, which will treat each character as byte, not UTF-8